# Is there a similar Gnome Shell Extension like this one?

Tags: command-line, gnome, extension

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/11/monitor-status-indicator/

I need a Gnome Shell Extension that can Rotate the Screen like this one, just for Gnome Shell 3.18.

I couldn't find anything like that.

Comment: That extension _is_ for 3.18. The latest versions are for 3.19, but there are still downloads available. I don't see the issue.

Comment: Right now I'm on Debian Testing with Gnome Shell 3.18.2 and when i try to install this Extensions nothing happens. And the gnome extensions website says this extension is not compatible with my version of gnome.

Comment: Debian isn't Ubuntu, and you have to use Firefox to Install from the browser.

Comment: I've tried it with Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 too, but that didn't work either with Gnome 3.18.2
And I'm using Firefox.

Comment: Then I recommend you install `gnome-tweak-tool` and manually install the  extension.

Answer (score 2):

That extension is available for GNOME 3.18. The second-to-latest download says that it is for 3.18. If you don't want to bother clicking the second link, here's the direct download:

https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell-extensions/snapshot/gnome-shell-extensions-3.18.4.zip